# Как получить Map<Integer, Entity> с помощью Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, java-ee

Есть некая сущность Entity:

- id
- name

Как с помощью Hibernate получить Map,чтобы в качестве ключа был id сущности, а значением сама сущность?
Можно, конечно,получить весь список сущностей и заполнить пустую map, но, наверное, есть более элегантный способ.